# Removing lines from original file after using tail command

Tags: linux

So I've got two files `input.txt` and `output.txt` and I'm using the command below to move the last 3000 lines from input to output:

`tail -n 3000 input.txt >> output.txt`

However, this leaves input still containing the last 3000 lines which were appended to output - but I want to remove the 3000 lines from input.

How would I go about doing this? Would I be able to use the `sed` command with this?

**EDIT:**

I tried the following: `tail -n 3000 input.txt >> output.txt; tail -n -3000 input.txt > file.txt.tmp; cp file.txt.tmp input.txt; rm file.txt.tmp`

However, it performs the copying into the new file as desired - however, instead of removing the last 3000 lines it removes everything *but* the last 3000.

Thanks.

Comment: as the answer by user Bernhard says, it's `head -n +3000 input.txt > tmpfile.txt`  -- note the plus sign, it's important. Your edit doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` is unnecessary. `head -n +number` returns everything but the `n` last lines. So try these commands:

```
tail -n 3000 input.txt >> output.txt
head -n +3000 input.txt > input.txt.truncated
mv input.txt.truncated input.txt
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18128546)

Comment: Actually I think it does. But I rephrased my answer with a bit of explanation to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for taking action on this